# Is there any difference between canned pineapple and fresh pineapple?

Tags: infant, food

We received a brochure showing all the recommended food for a baby, but it shows Pineapple (canned). I am wondering if there is any difference between feeding canned and fresh pineapple for a baby?

Answer (score 6):

Fresh pineapple contains significantly more [bromelain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple#Bromelain) than canned pineapple which has been cooked. If you make jello the package will note not to use fresh pineapple since the bromelain prevents the jello from setting.

Comment: I agree. Fresh pineapple can be tough (fibrous) and very acidic. The American Academy of Pediatrics  encourages parents to proceed with caution when giving citrus and other acidic fruits to younger babies. When I (an adult) eat fresh pineapple, it strips of layers of epidrermis from my tongue, leaving my mouth sore. As good as it tastes, it's not something I choose to eat often.

Comment: I was born in Hawaii, so I was fed pineapple at an early age.  I was nearly twelve, after so many ear infections that my eardrums are badly scarred, before my folks figured out that I had developed an allergy to citric acid.  Several doctors agreed that being fed pineapple as an infant probably caused the severity of the allergy.  Pineapple is extremely acidic.  My dentist said it's very harsh on teeth as well.  There are many other foods that are just as healthy and not as potentially harmful, I'd never feed even the juice to a youngster.